# Do I really need to be Installing AWS Common Runtime for PHP to work with the AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I'm using the AWS SKP for PHP in a Laravel app. When I try to create a client (for EventBridge in my case) I am getting the following error:

```
Aws\Exception\CommonRuntimeException : AWS Common Runtime for PHP is required to use Signature V4A.
```

The error includes a [link with information](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-php) on installing it, however, I have kind of a hard time believing that Jeff Bazos has abused his developers so horribly they have decided to create an API which can only run on their own Runtime just to spite any developer trying to use their API.

I haven't found much at all about this online which seems unlikely, but is this strictly necessary or is there was way to authenticate without going through the process of trying to install the AWS Common Runtime on my docker box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it unless you're using very specific features.  It works perfectly without it for almost all use cases.  Right now there's one method on eventbridge that needs it, and multi-region access points for S3.

General authentication information can be found here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html

Environment variables, the config file, or hardcoding (not recommended for security reasons) are gonna be the fastest way to get it up and running.

Comment: So I'm using the postEntities on EventBridge ... I'm guessing that is the one that requires it.  I ended up creating an endpoint in API Gateway, and passing to Eventbridge via that. Maybe most the cleanest way, but must more straightforward for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just "install it", but have to build a PHP module, to meet dependency `aws/aws-crt-php`:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-php ...that build script goes into your `Dockerfile` + an `*.ini`.